# Adding text to a JTextPane from another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane, documentfilter

I am trying to add strings to a JTextPane from another class, but it won't update the JTextPane. Ive tried threads, and now Ive been leaning towards a documentlistener or document filter. Apparently DocumentFilter is for updating JTextPane Docs, but is it possible to do this from another class and have it update as I add strings?
Ive tried something along the lines of:

```
textPane.insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,String str, AttributeSet a)
```

but NetBeans doesnt recognize the parameters. Thanks for your help.

*some clarification, by update I mean it actually shows the change on the JTextPane.

Answer (score 1):

> Ive been leaning towards a documentlistener or document filter

A DocumentListner notifies you when changes have been made to a Document. A DocumentFilter allows you to filter the text BEFORE the Document is changed.

> Ive tried something along the lines of:

```
textPane.insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,String str, AttributeSet a)
```

You should NOT be accessing the DocumentFilter directly. The DocumentFilter is access the the Document when you invoke the insertString() method on the Document.

Instead you should just be invoking the insertString() method of the Document:

```
textPane.getDocument().insertString(int offs,String str, AttributeSet a)
```

Comment: So if I invoke the insertString() method of the document will this add a string to the doc and also update the JTextPane as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing from different threads you need to use invokeLater from SwingUtilities

```
public void updateTextPane(final String text){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          updateTextPane(text);
        }
    });
}
```

remember to define text as final, it is not a problem about String being immutable btw